# Display link-changes in edit-history diff?

Tags: bug, status-completed, edits, user-interface

There's a problem with the diff, when someone edits a link the change isn't visible.

For example, if someone changed the URL from `http://example.com/something-05` to `http://example.com/something-06`, it wouldn't be obvious.

In fact, I can demonstrate it here, I think: [Example link](https://example.net) (check the revision history!)

Comment: Would be useful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It took more than two years, but this is finally [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) (as you can see in your question's [revision history](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/1370/revisions).

Answer (score 1):

> In fact, I can demonstrate it here, I think:

I think example.com changed to example.net. Hover with the mouse over the link. Status bar will tell you.

You are right that it could be shown more obviously in the revision history.

Comment: Indeed, but when there's several links in a long post, it gets very difficult to find.. In the example image, there was 6 URLs and only one character had changed! You can use the view source links for each, and manually diff them, but that's tedious..