# Please highlight hyperlink changes in suggested edit diffs

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, hyperlinks, suggested-edits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Display link-changes in edit-history diff?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1370/display-link-changes-in-edit-history-diff)

The diff of suggested edits only highlights differences in visible text, not differences in hyperlink targets. Sure, the targets are visible in the markdown diff, but who routinely checks that? This is a vector for spam: stealthily edit a link under the cover of some other helpful edit, and it's likely to be accepted. Any hyperlink whose target has changed should be highlighted as a difference.

Comment: I could have sworn there was a question here about a week ago, asking that hyperlinks be made more visible in the suggested edit diffs. But I can't seem to find it now...