# Highlight hyperlink changes in suggested edit diffs (again?)

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits, hyperlinks

Changes to hyperlinks are not easily distinguished in the suggested edit diffs.

This is particularly a problem when links are added - when a user updates or adds a link in an edit, I like to view/follow it to make sure it's valid.

However, to know if they added a link, I've got to hover my mouse over all of their edits to see if the link-indicating blue line appears under the text. This is not ideal.

This was [apparently fixed a while ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93401/please-highlight-hyperlink-changes-in-suggested-edit-diffs)? Perhaps it's come back.

[image: Y U NO DISTINGUISH LINKS?]

Feature request: **Visually identify links that are in green or red suggested edit blocks.**

*Supplementary request: Show the actual link href diff (if it changed) without requiring us to hover over it and view it in our browser's status bar.*